# How to set X-Frame-Options?

Tags: .htaccess, x-frame-options

can you tell me please where do I set these options on the server (godaddy linux apache)? shoudl I just place them in htaccess file?

Header set X-Frame-Options: “ALLOW_FROM https://specificdomain.com”
Header set Content-Security-Policy: “frame-ancestors https://specificdomain.com”

Comment: Yes, in .htaccess file in your domain root folder ex. public_html/

Comment: thank you - is this the correct syntax for apache? Header set X-Frame-Options: “ALLOW_FROM https://specificdomain.com”

Comment: Header set X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM https://specificdomain.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can put it in .htacces file 
like this

```
Header always set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"
```

for more information [read on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: thanks!! how do I allow my own site and a few domains? just put these lines in row?

Comment: I saw this info - it is correct??Enable on Apache#
To enable on Apache simply add it to your httpd.conf file (Apache config file).

header always set x-frame-options "SAMEORIGIN"

Comment: i dont think you can use this with multiple domains but you can try it: -in the same string -or  with `Header always append X-FRAME-OPTIONS ...`  .
(if my answer was correct please mark it as answer)

Comment: @TheBlueOne,  I have tried your code and added in the .htaccess file but I am getting the Internal Server Error